# How to create a custom switch in Nativescript

Tags: android, mobile, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to figure out how to implement this design in NativeScript for android. Which apis should I be accessing or is there a package I can use?

[image: switch mockup]

Comment: Please check this : https://lalitjadav007.blogspot.in/2017/03/custom-switch-library-for-android-easy.html

Answer (score 1):

Brad Martin has a [tutorial](https://bradmartin.net/2016/01/05/use-the-android-checkbox-with-nativescript/) on how to do something very similar.

Easy way would be to have a clickable `<Image>` which would show different image based on it's checked property. Like this [example](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ng-todomvc/blob/master/app/checkbox.ts) on official NativeScript repo.

Comment: What if there is a need of animation between states.. A lot of people are recommending images but seriously that is not the right solution, especially if the app is serious and made for normal users (non-enterprise)

Comment: Your best bet would be to follow the tutorial I posted - create native component, but you'd need to do it twice - for iOS and for Android.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for. If there's nothing out there, that's fine. I'll look at making one =)